# Importing from Python subdirectories

Tags: python

This should be straight forward, but I'm not sure whether it's my Eclipse config or my Python.

I've got a 2 files /trunk/shared/foo/bar.py
and /trunk/shared/foo/io.py

There is an __init__.py there too and in shared.

All I want to do is import io.py in bar.py.  I've tried import io, import foo.io and import shared.foo.io (as well as trunk.shared.foo.io).  None of these work, failing with the usual unresolved.

Cheers,
Joe

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: the path is currently set as ./trunk/

Answer (score 1):

To allow something like this : 
`import share.foo.bar`

You should have something like this :

```
trunk/
      shared/__init__.py
             foo/__init__.py
                 bar.py
                 io.py
```

The `__init__.py` (they must be empty in this case) files are needed to tell to python that it found a python module (ie : something you could import).

Comment: @Cédric: why oh why would you put `__init__.py` at the root of the project?

Comment: @Chris I haven't got it in trunk, it's not needed.  I've got it in the other folders although I don't understand why they are needed.

Comment: @Cédric I just want to import io.py

Comment: They don't *need* to be empty.

Comment: OK, well now without `__init__.py` in trunk, I'm inclined to agree with @Cédric. Use this structure, and from trunk run `from shared.foo import bar` and see what happens.

Comment: @Ignacio : I should precise that "for debug purpose they should be empty", in a real world you can do funny things with code in `__init__.py` files